# is apply method in companion object functor in scala?

Tags: scala, functor

As I know `functor` is a function returning a module from other module

Such that its signature is `* -> *`

Then by definition, is `apply` method in Companion object a functor ??

For example,

```
 case class A(id: Double)
 object A {
     def apply(intId: Int) = A(intId.toDouble) // Functor: Double -> A
 }
```

Am I right??

**My Questions** are

1) can `apply` method in companion object be viewed as Functor?

2) If `functor` is a just function that create an instance from other instance, what is the difference between functor and constructor

Comment: Which functor are we talking about? The mathematical definition or one from scalaz/cats?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thank for your comment. I am talking about mathematical definition of functor.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: It looks like the OP is talking about the ML concept of a Functor, where Functors are a feature of the module system. Modules in ML aren't first-class, so you can't pass them to a function or return them from a function. Functors are essentially functions inside the module system: they take modules as arguments and return modules. (Another meaning of Functor is the one from C++, which basically means any object that has an `operator()`.)

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not a definition of anything:

> As I know functor is a function returning a module from other module
>   Such that its signature is * -> *

And in the context of Scala, which modules are you talking about?

If you're [talking about mathematical definition of functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372280/is-apply-method-in-companion-object-functor-in-scala#comment68001113_40372280), let's first clarify what is a [functor in mathematics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functor#idea):

A functor between two [categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category) is a **pair of maps**: between their *objects* and their *morphisms*, such that they satisfy certain axioms (in short that it respects source/target of the morphisms and respects composition).

So first, before talking about any functors, you need to set up some context: a functor between which categories? What are their objects and what are their morphisms?

Then you can define a functor by defining how it maps those objects and how it maps morphisms.

So I can't give any answers to your questions, because
1) a method is just a map between values of two types, where are any categories here?
2) the phrase "functor is a just function" already doesn't make sense.

---

Now, the usual context in which people speak about [functors in programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2030863/736957) in general and [in Scala in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7576921/736957) is by defining a category which has (Scala) *types* as its objects and *functions* as its mophisms.

Then you can consider functors from this category to itself (which are called *endofunctors*), so in Scala it can be any parametrized type, which you can map over. For example, you can view `List[_]` as a functor:

- it maps any type `A` to type `List[A]`
- and by using it's method `.map` you can map a function `A => B` to a function `List[A] => List[B]`

To be a real functor, it has also satisfy the mentioned axioms, but let's leave them aside for simplicity.

Another example of a category in the context of Scala (or any similar programming language) is one with Scala types (again) as objects and the morphisms being the subtype relation: `A :> B`.

Check the linked related questions for more details and examples.

---

So if you can provide enough of such context, then update your question and ask in the comments if you don't understand something.